# Selecting part of a line after excluding lines that begin with a specific expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I can match what I'm looking for and I can exclude the right lines, but when I try to do both, things go wonky

I've tried a bunch of crap on regexr and other sites but I'm probably missing some fundamentals of regex.

I'm trying to match the equals sign and after except on lines starting with (space)(space)type:

```
something = something

somethingelse = something

  type = something
```

The regex that captures what I want:

```
=.*
```

The regex that excludes the type line:

```
^(?!  type)
```

Putting it together matches nothing:

```
^(?!  type)=.*
```

Unless I want the whole line:

```
^(?!  type).*
```

ideally the first two lines would be captured from the equals sign to the end of the line.

Comment: You can add `?` after character that would appear once, or not appear at all.
Do you need [this](https://regex101.com/r/kBaeXo/1) regex: `^(?!  type)=?.*` ?

Comment: Nope didn't work. I want to capture "= something" on the first two lines while not matching everything before the equals sign

Comment: Then i suggest you use groups instead of lookarounds. You can extract desired part of the match with groups (they adjust text pointer, whlist lookarounds do not change it)

Comment: PCRE: `^(?!  type).*?\K=.*`. C#: `(?<!^ type.*?)=.*`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that worked :)

Comment: Should I post any? I see the solution below works too, so some of these can't work for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a capturing group and a negated character class to first match any char except an equals sign or a newline.

Then match the `=` and capture the rest of the line in a group.

```
^(?!  type\b)[^=\r\n]*=(.*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!  type\b)` Assert what is directly on the right is not 2 spaces `type` and a word boundary
- `[^=\r\n]*=` Match 0+ times not `=` or a newline
- `(.*)` Capture any char except a newline in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/943Yyz/1)

Comment: works, thanks for the explanation and link that helped me break down the parts better :)